# Level1 Matlab S-function - "Work Vectors"

Tags: matlab, simulink, s-function

I'm using a Matlab level 1 S-function several times in a model but don't want the mutual overwriting of global/persistent variables.

A solution could be work vectors but there is little documentation about level 1 S-function work vectors. Where do i get the SimStruct S for the ssSetNumRWork function?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right thing to do is upgrade the code to be a level-2 S-Function, which shouldn't be difficult.

Level 1 m-code S-functions don't have work vectors (and all of the ssGet/Set functions are for c-code S-Functions anyway).  A reason they aren't recommended any more is that they have limited functionality -- there's no nice way of getting around that without using Level 2 functionality.

You can use persistent variables (within each subfunction of a level-1 S-Function).  But the point of global variables to enable them to be seen everywhere, so trying to use them without wanting everyone to see them seems pointless.  (Note: you should never use global variables anyway.)

Having said that, if you really want to use Level-1 functionality, then within each S-Function you can use the [getappdata](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/getappdata.html) and [setappdata](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/setappdata.html) functions to act like work vector storage.  But if you're going to go to that trouble, upgrading to a level-2 S-function will be easier anyway.

Comment: OK! i'll try upgrading using this [link](http://de.mathworks.com/help/simulink/sfg/maintaining-level-1-matlab-s-functions.html#bq3i98j) - there are elementary w.v. [link](http://de.mathworks.com/help/simulink/sfg/elementary-work-vectors.html), but how to access e.g. "RWork" in matlab if ssGet/Set is for C ?

Comment: See the [Writing Level-2 MATLAB S-Functions](http://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/sfg/writing-level-2-matlab-s-functions.html) doc for an example of Work Vectors and how to use them.

Comment: Is it possible that the runtime of a level-2 s-function is longer than that of a level-1 even if its the "same" code? from 1min to 2min..

Comment: There is unlikely to be that much difference.